# Scala-Spark NullPointerError when submitting jar, not in shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

My spark job raises a null pointer exception that I cannot trace down. When I print potential null variables, they're all populated on every worker. My data does not contain null values as the same job works within the spark shell. The execute function of the job is below, followed by the error message.

All helper methods not defined in the function are defined within the body of the spark job object, so I believe closure is not the problem.

```
override def execute(sc:SparkContext) = {
  def construct_query(targetTypes:List[String]) = Map("query" ->
    Map("nested" ->
      Map("path"->"annotations.entities.items",
        "query"-> Map("terms"->
          Map("annotations.entities.items.type"-> targetTypes)))))

  val sourceConfig = HashMap(
    "es.nodes" -> params.targetClientHost
  )

  // Base elastic search RDD returning articles which match the above query on entity types
  val rdd = EsSpark.esJsonRDD(sc,
    params.targetIndex,
    toJson(construct_query(params.entityTypes)),
    sourceConfig
  ).sample(false,params.sampleRate)

  // Mapping ES json into news article object, then extracting the entities list of
  // well defined annotations
  val objectsRDD = rdd.map(tuple => {
    val maybeArticle =
      try {
        Some(JavaJsonUtils.fromJson(tuple._2, classOf[SearchableNewsArticle]))
      }catch {
        case e: Exception => None
      }
    (tuple._1,maybeArticle)
  }
  ).filter(tuple => {tuple._2.isDefined && tuple._2.get.annotations.isDefined &&
    tuple._2.get.annotations.get.entities.isDefined}).map(tuple => (tuple._1, tuple._2.get.annotations.get.entities.get))

  // flat map the RDD of entities lists into a list of (entity text, (entity type, 1)) tuples
  (line 79) val entityDataMap: RDD[(String, (String, Int))] = objectsRDD.flatMap(tuple => tuple._2.items.collect({
    case item if (item.`type`.isDefined) && (item.text.isDefined) &&
   (line 81)(params.entityTypes.contains(item.`type`.get))  => (cleanUpText(item.text.get), (item.`type`.get, 1))
  }))

  // bucketize the tuples RDD into entity text, List(entity_type, entity_count) to make count aggregation and file writeouts
 // easier to follow
 val finalResults: Array[(String, (String, Int))] = entityDataMap.reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1, x._2+y._2)).collect()

  val entityTypeMapping = Map(
    "HealthCondition" -> "HEALTH_CONDITION",
    "Drug" -> "DRUG",
    "FieldTerminology" -> "FIELD_TERMINOLOGY"
  )

  for (finalTuple <- finalResults) {
    val entityText = finalTuple._1
    val entityType = finalTuple._2._1
    if(entityTypeMapping.contains(entityType))
    {
                if(!Files.exists(Paths.get(entityTypeMapping.get(entityType).get+".txt"))){
        val myFile = new java.io.FileOutputStream(new   File(entityTypeMapping.get(entityType).get+".txt"),false)
        printToFile(myFile) {p => p.println(entityTypeMapping.get(entityType))}
      }
    }
    val myFile = new java.io.FileOutputStream(new   File(entityTypeMapping.get(entityType).get+".txt"),true)
    printToFile(myFile) {p => p.println(entityText)}
  }

}
```

And the error message below:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.quid.gazetteers.GazetteerGenerator$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.isDefinedAt(GazetteerGenerator.scala:81)
>     at
>   com.quid.gazetteers.GazetteerGenerator$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.isDefinedAt(GazetteerGenerator.scala:79)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:278)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.collect(TraversableLike.scala:278)
>     at
>   scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.collect(Traversable.scala:105)
>     at
>   com.quid.gazetteers.GazetteerGenerator$$anonfun$4.apply(GazetteerGenerator.scala:79)
>     at
>   com.quid.gazetteers.GazetteerGenerator$$anonfun$4.apply(GazetteerGenerator.scala:79)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been resolved. The params attribute was not serialized and available to spark workers. The solution is to form a spark broadcast variable within scope of the areas where the params attribute is needed.

Comment: do we have code snippet of how it has been resolved?